# Firebase NodeJS Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have built a fairly basic ExpressJS app and am using Firebase for authentication. When the app loads it checks to see if a user is logged in and if not shows the login screen. The user then enters an email and password and this does a POST to my express ass and logs in the user like so:

```
app.post('/login-user', function(req, res) {
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email1, req.body.password1).then(function(authData){
   res.redirect('/')
 }).catch(function(error) {
   console.log('mainError', error)
   console.log('error', error.code);
   console.log('message', error.message);
 });
});
```

This works absolutely fine and the user is logged in and i can access their AuthData.

The issue is this logs the whole app into firebase. If I access the app on another computer it automatically logs in with this user. So basically, only one user can be logged in at one time.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What's happening is your server's firebase instance itself it's being authenticated instead of returning the authentication data to the client. What you should be doing is returning the client authentication token on the request. There's a section covering server authentication here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/#create_a_custom_token

Comment: Also take a look at the Admin SDK, there's a link in the same page, It may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @ItaloAyres so do I still use the above "signInWithEmailAndPassword()" in my node app to generate AuthData and then get the UID to create a token? Once I have the token I send it back to the client and then use it to login using token?

Comment: No, you'll need to use complete different methods. This one is used by clients only. You now want to use the admin SDK which uses an unique identifier to log the user in, with `createCustomToken(uid)`. And then, the client will need to pass the token on every request, and the server will need to verify it also on every request, using `verifyIdToken(idToken)` .

Comment: I recommend you studding the basics on how token based authentication works. Also the Firebase docs are quite easy to understand.