# My Firebase website only allows one user logged in at all times, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

**SITUATION:**

If I log in from one device and open the website on any other device (my phone, my friend's laptop, my neighbour's pc), the website shows me as logged in on all those devices.

If I log out, I am shown as logged out on all devices.

Effectively, my website can only be used by one user at a time which is absolutely pointless.

I must somehow have misused Firebase authentication.

---

**CODE:**

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('users/login', {
            errors: errors
        });
    } else {

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(authData => { 

            console.log("Authenticated user with uid:",authData);
            req.flash('success_msg', 'You have logged in');
            res.redirect("/fun/index");

        }).catch(error => { 

            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log("Login Failed: ", error);
            req.flash('error_msg', "Unknown user or password");
            res.redirect('/users/login');

        });
    }
});
```

---

**QUESTION:**

What mistake have I made and how do I fix it ?

---

**EDIT:** Found this: [Firebase NodeJS Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749038/firebase-nodejs-authentication)

But the question remained without an answer.

Comment: You can't fix it easily, as you appear to have chosen to sign in the user on your server. A single, initialized Firebase API app can have only one signed-in user and that's your problem. I vaguely remember this being mentioned in a comment that was posted to one of your previous questions.

Comment: @cartant Maybe it's as simple as signing in on the client side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the [node.js admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/), you are effectively in a single-user situation, and your server is the single user.  Typically, that single user is a privileged service account, but it appears you're using it to log in individual users simultaneously.  That's not a supported use case for the admin SDK.

If you want per-user login for your web site, you'll have to authenticate in the browser itself using the [web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).  The web SDK communicates directly with Firebase services, securely, on behalf of the user that's signed in.

Comment: I used the same kind of logic on the server for logout and register.

Comment: Does that mean there will only be one logout or register at the same time ?

Comment: Do I need to move everything to the client ? Is there no way to change my logic but keep most of it on the server ?

Comment: I am using the web SDK btw, but on my sever side.

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look. But also please answer to:  
"Does that mean there will only be one logout or register at the same time ?"