# Why is firebase.auth().currenUser null?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

**EDIT2:**

**CODE:**

```
<script>
    console.log("CURRENT USER:"+firebase.auth().currentUser);

    var inElements = document.getElementsByClassName('authIn');
    var outElements = document.getElementsByClassName('authOut');

    if (firebase.auth().currentUser == null) {

        for(var i=0; i < inElements.length; i++) { 
            inElements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for(var i=0; i < outElements.length; i++) { 
            outElements[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        }
    }
    else {

        for(var i=0; i < inElements.length; i++) { 
            inElements[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        }
        for(var i=0; i < outElements.length; i++) { 
            outElements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I log in, firebase.auth().currentUser is null.

---

**QUESTION:**

Why and how do I fix it ?

---

**LOGIN CODE:**

```
<script>


            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password ).then( authData => {
             //A LOT OF CODE FOR DIFFERENT SITUATIONS


            },function(error) { 

                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local', "Unknown user or password");
                window.location.href="/users/login";
                console.log("Login Failed: ", error);

            });


</script>
```

---

In the login code, I show different kinds of error messages depending on how the authentication went. There is also some code to manage verified and unverified accounts.

Comment: The simplest way to keep from sending email/password in the URL is to change the form to use `POST`: `<form method="POST">`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's what I had before. But doesn't it send the data on the  server side ? Which means I am then back to square one with only one user logged in at all times.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579003/my-firebase-website-only-allows-one-user-logged-in-at-all-times-why

Comment: @hotrod I read the entire docs. Not helping :P

Comment: I can't understand what you are doing. You seem to be mixing backend and front end code. You do not need to send anything to your server. Password authentication runs on the client side completely.

Comment: @bojeil I know. That's why all my code is on the client side now. But I need answers to 1) and 2). Using POST means I need to go back to my server code, or am I wrong ?

Comment: You don't need to send a POST request to your server, unless you have some other reason to. You can handle the operation in the client completely.

Comment: @bojeil Ideally, I would like the code to be executed on the server and send back a custom Token to the client for authentication. But I don't know how to do that AND YES, I have read the docs pertaining to that.

Comment: @Coder1000 you want to use the admin SDK (- server side) or the web SDK? Or in other words you want to use signInWithEmailAndPassword - you need to be on client side, using the server side you would need createCustomToken / verifyToken on server and signInWithCustomToken on client side.

Comment: @axel.michel Ideally, I would like to keep my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579003/my-firebase-website-only-allows-one-user-logged-in-at-all-times-why   on the server side an be able to log in more than one user. The person who gives me a working answer with code gets the bounty :)

Comment: @Coder1000 you can't keep that code on the server side the method signInWithEmailAndPassword is part of the client side SDK, it's a decision you'll have to make - stay with the method, switch to client, stay server side,  switch the methods.

Comment: @axel.michel I am fine with switching methods. I just would like to keep my server code and be able to authenticate my users, that's all :)

Comment: @Coder1000 in that case, the firebase docs provide a fine example, can you tell me what is unclear, or not working? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens ?

Comment: @axel.michel I have users UIDs saved in my databse. How can I send back  to the client a custom token that's just the UID of my user before he has even logged in ?

Comment: Typically you would sign in the users with an email and password using your own custom code assuming you maintain these users on your own (you have your own database). You do not use signInWithEmailAndPassword or Firebase there. You post the email and password to your server, verify that account using your own auth system and on success, mint a custom token with your user's uid and then return it to the client where the client signs in via signInWithCustomToken using that custom token to complete the flow.

Comment: @bojeil  That makes total sense ! But I don't have my own authentication system, I use Firebase for that. Does this mean I have no other option than moving all my authentication to the client ?

Comment: @Coder1000 Yes use firebase to manage your users.  No interaction with the server is required.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users  Are you having trouble implementing this?  I can provide an example if it would be helpful..

Comment: @Trevor No, I have no trouble implementing this. My problem is with with points 1) and 2) of my question. I would like to avoid passing the parameters in the url. I would still prefer to be able to keep my authentication code on the server. It has grown a bit more complex than what you currently see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `authdata` variable so that it reflects whether the user is logged in or not.

You can run this code on initialization which creates an observer on the firebase Auth object.  Anytime a logout/login change happens the `authdata` variable will be updated accordingly..

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    authdata = user;
  }
  else {
   authdata = null;
  }
});
```

Alternatively if for some reason you don't want the observer approach you can simply set your `authdata` like so:

```
authdata = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

If the user is not logged in authdata will be set to null and your `ejs` should update accordingly..

I'm assuming your `ejs` is running on the client.  If it's not then your `ejs` template won't pick up on these changes.

You'll want to load the `ejs` script client side and run your template from there.

See: [EJS Client Side Support](https://github.com/mde/ejs#client-side-support) for reference.

Comment: Your approach seems absolutely correct, but I would prefer a full javascript approach. Could you please have  a  look at my edited question ? Sadly firebase.auth().currentUser is null :/

Comment: @Coder1000, what kind of authentication are you using?  Or can you explain/show how an account is created?  For example you can use firebases build in authentication, or Custom Authentication. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: I am using email authentication

Comment: @Coder1000, see if you are getting any errors when signing in: firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code,
        errorMessage = error.message;
  debugger;
});

Comment: I know there are no errors in that. I have a console.log inside my code that gets printed once logged in successfully.

Comment: Also, I don't know where to place `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: @Coder1000 lets discuss in chat.